# Understanding C++ std::shared_ptr when used with temporary objects

Tags: c++, syntax, expression, shared-ptr, declaration

I am trying to understand the use of a `shared_ptr p` when it is used in the construction of an unnamed `shared_ptr` and the effects this has on `p`. I was toying with my own examples and wrote the following piece of code:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));
cout << p.use_count() << '\n';          
{ 
  cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
  shared_ptr<int>(p);
  cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
}
cout << p.use_count() << '\n';

Output:
1
1
0
1
```

1. Is it correct that line 5, uses `p` to create a temp. `shared_ptr` (i.e
   an unnamed `shared_ptr`)?
2. If so why isn't the `use_count` increased. Is the temp.object destroyed even 
   before we exit the block at line 7.
3. If it is destroyed and `p`'s use count becomes zero inside the block, 
   how come it is 1 again after we exit the block?

If I would have used a named `shared_ptr` `q` on line 5, i.e:

```
shared_ptr<int>q(p);
```

Everything would work as expected, inside the block after line 5 the 
use count would be 2 and after we exit the block it would be 1 again.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the line `shared_ptr<int>(p);` actually declares a null shared ptr called p that shadows the first one.

Comment: And this is actually pointed out by Clang: `warning: parentheses were disambiguated as redundant parentheses around declaration of variable named 'p' [-Wvexing-parse]`

Comment: C++ syntax has a few gotchyas for the unwary.  You found one!  (Where "few" can only be counted using transcendental numbers.)

Comment: @sturcotte06 whoah, I did not know it works that way, I actually perceived that as an unnamed temporary. Can anynone please point me to cppreference which says what rule covers this? Glad I learned something new.

Comment: `shared_ptr<int>{p}` would create the temporary.

Comment: That is why C++11 introduces braces for initialization.

Comment: [here is cppcon where this trap is described as recurring bug in C++ code](https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (8.5.1.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation))

> 1 A simple-type-specifier (10.1.7.2) or typename-specifier (17.7)
>   followed by a parenthesized optional expressionlist or by a
>   braced-init-list (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified
>   type given the initializer...

So the expression in this expression statement

```
shared_ptr<int>(p);
```

looks like an explicit type conversion (functional) expression.

On the other hand, a declarator in a declaration can be enclosed in parentheses. For example

```
int ( x );
```

is a valid declaration.

So this statement

```
shared_ptr<int>(p);
```

can be interpretated as a declaration like

```
shared_ptr<int> ( p );
```

So there is an abiguity.

The C++ Standard resolves this ambiguity the following way (9.8 Ambiguity resolution)

> 1 There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
>   and declarations: An expression statement with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (8.5.1.3) as its leftmost subexpression can
>   be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator
>   starts with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration**.

Thus this statement in the inner code  block

```
shared_ptr<int>(p);
```

is a declaration of a new shared pointer with the name `p` that hides the previous declaration of the object with the same name `p` in the outer code block and that is created by using the defalut constructor

```
constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;
```

According to the description of this constructor

> 2 Effects: Constructs an empty shared_ptr object.
>
> 3 Postconditions: **use_count() == 0** && get() == nullptr.

If you want to deal with an expression instead of the declaration then all you need to do is to enclose the body of the statement in parentheses getting a primary expression in an expression statement.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p( new int( 42 ) );

    std::cout << "#1: " << p.use_count() << '\n';          

    { 
        std::cout << "#2: " << p.use_count() << '\n';

        ( std::shared_ptr<int>( p ) );

        std::cout << "#3: " << p.use_count() << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "#4: " << p.use_count() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In this case its output is

```
#1: 1
#2: 1
#3: 1
#4: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

1. no

In line 5 you create new variable p. Empty one. See this:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));
cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
cout << "address " << &p << "\n";
{
    cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
    shared_ptr<int>(p);
    cout << "address " << &p << "\n";
    cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
}
cout << p.use_count() << '\n';
```

output:

```
1
address 0x7ffcf3841860
1
address 0x7ffcf3841870
0
1
```

Note, that address of p has changed.

To fix it change parenthesis:

```
shared_ptr<int> {p};
```

Comment: You should probably mention how to fix it by using curly braces instead: `shared_ptr<int>{p};`

Comment: Thank you, fixed.

Comment: @user3041122 Always compile your code with warnings enabled. If you use GCC or Clang, you should at least use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: I see, thank you! I read in c++ primer that the following snippet: int *x(new int(1024)); followed by a call to to a function that takes a shared_ptr as param: process(share_ptr<int>(x));  Is passing process a (temporary) shared_ptr. Is this case different than my case? Since we are passing a built-in ptr x ?

Comment: @user3041122 It's different, because you can't declare variables inside the paretheses of a function call. So this could not be parsed as a variable declaration.

Comment: It's different. In short expression, that looks like `value1(value2)` might be interpreted differently based on what `value1` is. If there's a type, then it becomes a variable definition and parenthesis become redundant. `process(shared_ptr<int>(x))` is different, compiler knows, that process is a function identifier, so whole thing become an expression and `shared_ptr<int>(x)` becomes constructor of temporary value, instead of variable.

Comment: Nikos, thank you for the comments. On page 466 in C++ Primer, they use the parantheses without adequate explanation of what is going or it is somekind of typo. In any case I see the difference now when using braces vs parentheses.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Now I understand what's going on. =).

Answer (score 2):

`shared_ptr<int>(p);` is equivalent to `shared_ptr<int> p;`, essentially creating another `p` inside that block that hides the previous `p`. The parentheses here are not a constructor call, but are interpreted by the compiler like mathematical parentheses grouping an expression, the expression being the name of the newly constructed shared_ptr.

`shared_ptr<int>q(p);` instead creates a new shared_ptr named `q`, calling the constructor with a reference to `p` as parameter (thus increasing the ref count). The parentheses in this case are interpreted as enclosing the constructor argument.

Note that when you use curly brackets `{}`, `std::shared_ptr<int>q{p};` will continue to give the expected result (1 1 2 1), while `std::shared_ptr<int>{p};` will print  (1 1 1 1), because the compiler now considers the second `p` part of the tiny block surrounding it. The joy of programming in C++.

Comment: Good except for the misleading "calling the constructor" bits - even when you use `()` in a declaration, which may look a bit like a function call, you are not [directly] "calling the constructor", which is impossible: that is done for you by the machinery whilst other things are going on as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you mean using ( ) is not a constructor call? in above statement.