# C++ shared_ptr reference count while binding another smart pointer to pointer returned by get

Tags: c++, syntax, expression, shared-ptr, declaration

According to "C++ Primer" page 466, it is an error to bind another smart pointer to the pointer returned by `get()`. This is followed by some code and further explanation. I am having trouble understanding part of the explanation, which states verbatim:

> In this case, both p and q point to the same memory. Because they were created independently from each other, each has a reference count of 1. When the block in which q was defined ends, q is destroyed. Destroying q frees the memory to which q points. That makes p into a dangling pointer, meaning that what happens when we attempt to use p is undefined.

This question is related to a previous question I asked, [Understanding C++ std::shared_ptr when used with temporary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652083/), where I was toying with my own examples and erroneously believed that a temporary `shared_ptr` was being created on line 5.

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));
int *q = p.get();
{ // new block
  // undefined: two independent shared_ptrs point to same memory
  shared_ptr<int>(q); 
  cout << p.use_count() << '\n' << q.use_count() <<'\n';
}
```

> ```
> Output:
> 1
> 0
> ```

According to the explanation above, both `p` and `q` have a reference count of 1.

But when adding a print statement to output the reference counts. I get that `p` has use count of 1 but `q` has a use count of 0. Shouldn't `q` also have a use count of 1? Or am I missing something? I would understand if `q` reference count was 0 after the block.

Comment: The problem is about scoping, shadowing variable names in an inner scope, and a weird (but valid) syntax to declare variables.

Comment: If it were a temporary, your code wouldn't compile because `q` would be an `int*`.

Comment: @molbdnilo It compiles https://godbolt.org/z/fPwchN I expect shadowing even if I didnt know this can happen with different types

Comment: @Narase It compiles because there is no temporary. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/G_2IqV) is the same code but with an actual temporary. ("error: request for member 'use_count' in 'q', which is of non-class type 'int*'")

Answer (score 3):

> `shared_ptr<int>(q);`

This creates a shared_ptr with the name q and is equivalent to

```
shared_ptr<int> q;
```

Which does not point to anything and thus its count is 0

If you want a second shared_ptr pointing to q, you need this

```
 shared_ptr<int> p2(q);
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question and furthermore it seems to misunderstand my question. There is nothing "I want", my question is why has the newly created shared_ptr q reference count 0, when according to C++ primer it should have reference count 1.

Comment: @Sohof `shared_ptr<int>(q);` is same as `shared_ptr<int> q;`, i.e. declare a `shared_ptr` pointing to nothing.

Comment: @Sohof You misunderstand the answer. Sure you want something, its a second shared_ptr pointing to q and youre wondering why its count is 0. Its because you never linked them because you created an empty shared_ptr which, of course, has a count a 0, because it doesnt point to anything

Comment: @Narase so you mean when the book writes "// undefined two independent shared_ptrs point to the same memory" and further takes about destroying q makes p into a dangling pointer, that somehow they are never linked to begin with? And further why does the book say that q should have a reference count of 1 then? (According to my knowledge C++ Primer by Lippman is supposed to be a well respected book). Or am I still misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @Sohof Are you 100% sure the line in your book says ``shared_ptr<int>(q);`` ?

Comment: @Narase, Yes I am, at least in my version second printing 2012 (which is the latest one I believe. I suspected it being a typo in the book, but it was not listed in any errata. And the book is well respected, while I am a novice.. so.. I thought I must be wrong.

Comment: @Sohof Understandable. Its a mistake in the book then. Try the example again but with the line ``shared_ptr<int> p2(q);`` and you should see the expected results

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the book - in the inner block, `q` is an empty `shared_ptr`, unrelated to `p.get()`.

It seems that this has not made its way into any published errata.

The following should print what you expect, and be as undefined as the author intended:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));
{ 
  shared_ptr<int> q(p.get()); 
  cout << p.use_count() << '\n' << q.use_count() <<'\n';
}
```

Comment: I suspected something was wrong but wasn't sure about it being a bug in the book. As shown from my first question on this subject that I linked to, I had initially thought that a temporary was being created because the syntax really resembles that.